# Algebra and convex geometry for proving uniqueness of John ellipsoids

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, ellipsoids

I am looking at the proof about the uniqueness of [John ellipsoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid). The book I am looking at starts by supposing that there are two different ellipsoids $\epsilon:=S(\mathbb{B}_2^n)+x$ and $\epsilon^{'}:=S^{'}(\mathbb{B}_2 ^n)+x^{'}$ contained in a convex body $K$, both are John ellipsoids, where $S$ and $S^{'}$ are positive definite matrices. Now the book says, by **linear invariance** we may assume that $S=I$ identity matrix. What does it mean by **linear invariance**? can you help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Which book are you looking at?

Comment: It means that if $f$ is any invertible linear transformation, then $x$ is a John ellipsoid of a convex body $y$, if and only if $f(x)$ is a John ellipsoid of $f(y)$. So you can apply $S^{-1}$ to get an equivalent but simpler problem.